# adding pipe to values in java

Tags: java, for-loop, concatenation, pipe

I have some values which I have to bring them as pipe`|` separated and I have done like this :

```
List<String> transactionReferenceInfoList = paymentInfoDao.getTransactionRefNumberToVerify("0");

        for (String transactionRefNumber : transactionReferenceInfoList) {
            transactionID = transactionID + "|"+transactionRefNumber;
        }
```

this gives me what I want like the below :

```
|6503939|2298597|4786967|2855035|8999941|7331957|1829429|7148599
```

but it is having the `|` at the beginning of the value I want. how to I avoid this and is there any other best way to do this ?

Please suggest me if there is.

thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: transactionID.replaceFirst("[|]", "");

Comment: newuser, that is slow as hell.
Fastest solution is:
transactionID = transactionID.substring(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best practice is using Apache Commons Lang:

```
String transactionID = StringUtils.join(transactionReferenceInfoList , "|");
```

Or you may just put an if clause inside loop.

Comment: Or substring the result from index 1 ;-)

Comment: @Mustafa Genc :) thanks, it helped me, will mark your answer as accepted in few mins of time

Comment: what is the difference between using `for each loop` and `Apache Commons Lang`, Please share if you don't mind

Comment: Actually commons lang almost does the same thing. It's null-safe. It removes probability of making errors for these simple jobs. If you wonder about the performance, just measure it.

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel! do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use StringUtils.join from Apache Commons

```
StringUtils.join(transactionReferenceInfoList,'|');
```

Answer (score 1):

For first Iteration check if `transactionID` is null.

```
List<String> transactionReferenceInfoList = paymentInfoDao.getTransactionRefNumberToVerify("0");

        for (String transactionRefNumber : transactionReferenceInfoList) {
            if(transactionID==null)
                  transactionID=transactionRefNumber;
            transactionID = transactionID + "|"+transactionRefNumber;
        }
```

Comment: The condition will check every time. its needed or not

Comment: @R.S this is also one of the good one but I would prefer using `StringUtils.join from Apache Commons`. +1

Comment: @newuser Yes,this condition well get checked in each iteration.

Comment: If the list size is 1000 then this condition will check 1000 times. It need from the beginning only. Why at all those time

Answer (score 1):

maybe is strange answer but for making different change loop:

```
List<String> transactionReferenceInfoList = paymentInfoDao.getTransactionRefNumberToVerify("0");

        for (String transactionRefNumber : transactionReferenceInfoList) {

           transactionID+= transactionRefNumber+"|";

        }
```

and if you want delete the last "|"

if i don't understand your answer, i hope apologize me.

Comment: TaoBao, :) Thanks for your time... +1 for spending your time for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that each time that `|` is there,

Without any `Utils`  `String` class alone do that job with help of  `subString` method

```
resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length());
```

For ex:

```
String resultString  = "test";
resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length());
System.out.println(resultString);  //gives "est"
```

Comment: @Suresh Thanks for your time... +1 for spending your time for me

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> transactionReferenceInfoList = paymentInfoDao.getTransactionRefNumberToVerify("0");
int i = 0;
for (String transactionRefNumber : transactionReferenceInfoList) {
    if(i==0) {
        transactionID = transactionID + transactionRefNumber;
    } else {
        transactionID = transactionID + "|"+transactionRefNumber;
    }
    i++;
}
```

hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: Thanks for your time... +1 for spending your time for me

Answer (score -1):

List transactionReferenceInfoList = paymentInfoDao.getTransactionRefNumberToVerify("0");

```
    for (String transactionRefNumber : transactionReferenceInfoList) {
        transactionID = transactionID + "|"+transactionRefNumber; //|XXX|XXX
    }
var trasactionID_new =transactionID.substring(1);//XXX|XXX
```

Comment: A good answer needs some explanation. Not only some code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).